# Run a command before any terminal command

Tags: bash

Is there a way to run one command before any terminal command gets executed?

For example:

```
> ls -ltr
> "Hello you ran ls -ltr" //this is what I would like to achieve
> ..output of ls -ltr will be here
```

Is it possible to run make sure an echo runs before any command is executed?

Thanks

Comment: You have just described xtrace. `PS4='Hello, you ran: '; set -x`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might want to look into setting a `DEBUG` trap, which allows you to set up what is effectively a pre-exec hook in a manner similar to `zsh`.  See https://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command.

Answer (score 3):

Bash has the concept of assigning a function to ps1 so mine looks like

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1=$(make_ps1); set_xterm_title'
```

where make_ps1 is

```
    make_ps1()
    {
    if [ $? = 0 ];then
        echo '\[\e[${host_color}m\][\D{%F %T} \u@\h \W]\[\e[0m\]\n\$ '
    else
        echo '\[\e[7m\e[${host_color}m\][\D{%F %T} \u@\h \W]\[\e[0m\]\n\$ '
    fi
    }
```

you should be able to leverage that to do whatever you want, but it will run after the command is executed so this might not work for what you need.